# Passing generic typdef struct to function in C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I'am working on Arduino and I'am writing generic cpp class to comunicate in i2c. I would like to know if it's possible to pass a generic `typedef struct` representing a register in a function, something like this

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t not_used_01    : 1;
  uint8_t i3c_disable    : 1;
  uint8_t den_lh         : 2;
  //some other attributs
} reg_ctrl9_xl_t;

typedef struct {
  uint8_t not_used_01    : 1;
  uint8_t odr_h          : 1;
  uint8_t ord_lh         : 1;
  //some other attributs
} reg_ctrl5_g_t;
```

my header file

```
class I2c
{
   public:
      I2c(uint8_t address);
      void writeStruct(uint8_t register_addr, <what data type here??> register_struct); 
      //some other functions   
   private:
     uint8_t _address;   
}
```

I don't know if it's possible, I don't know which data type I should put in font of `register_struct` because here I have 2 register for example `reg_ctrl9_xl_t` and `reg_ctrl5_g_t` I'am looking for a generic parameters function for `writeStruct`

Comment: If you create a class `reg_ctrl` with a public pure virtual method `writeTo(uint8_t register_addr)`, then the classes `reg_ctrl9_xl` and `reg_ctrl5_g` for example can inherit from `reg_ctrl` and implement the method. When you want to store such a subclass it will then be able to be of type `reg_ctrl`.

Comment: Ok so I'll be looking for virtual method, I'am beginner in C++ :)

Comment: template might be an alternative, but it seems you need special code for each one, so overload seems more appropriated.

Comment: I've looked for template, but that is what I understood. If I use a template, I need to create one function for each typedef register, is it right ?

Comment: template avoid to manually copy-paste "same" code (overload resolution might differ, but tokens are identical) for different parameters, but there are indeed one function by parameter type. Here your members have different name, so I suppose you can't have directly the same code. overload seems more appropriate.

Comment: Definitely an overload. If you go for generic, you'll have to specialize it, which is same as overload in this case, but with more code.

Comment: I have implemented I2C for atmega32. You can check my implementation [here](https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/avr/avr_TWI_master_ioxtream.h). I overload `operator<<`.  (It depends on `avr_TWI_master.h` and also in `avr_TWI_basic.h`